# How can I solve create account problem with different providers?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have a sign in with **Google**:example@gmail.com

then create an account with the same **email**:example@gmail.com

There is a problem with two different providers

1. Sign in with Google (same Gmail)
2. Sign in with Email (same Gmail)

How Can I handle these two (**When I delete the google sign-in account from Firebase Console. I can create an account with that email**) Otherwise I can't create an account with that email and also can't sign in.

I learning Firebase Auth with https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first sign in with Google using "example@gmail.com", it means a user will be created using this particular email address. If you try to sign in with any other provider or with an email and password using the **same** email address, you'll get an error message that says that the user already exists. And it makes sense since you have already used that email for a user before.

There are two ways in which you can solve this problem. When you get such an error, you can check the provider used to create the account, and notify the user to use it. For example, if the user signs in with Google and tries to authenticate with email and password right after that, display a message to the user in which you should say that the user already exists, and should use the authentication provider which was selected to create the account in the first place, in this case, Google.

The second option would be to allow the user to have multiple accounts using the same email address with different authentication providers. This option can be enabled directly in the [Firebase Console](https://firebase.google.com/), in the Authentication section.

So it's up to you to decide which option works better for your project.

Comment: I have some questions with firebase Auth
I condition rendering the login Component and Dashboard Component. I think I need to store some key in cookies . My problem is when refresh the page, the user signed in but can see the login Component for a second. Do I need cookies? How Can I fix it .I use Next js

Comment: Without seeing the code you're using, I cannot be much of a help. If you have a hard time implementing that mechanism, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: I already asked that issue. still need help

Comment: Have you read my previous comment? Have you asked another question? I was asking if I can help you with other information regarding the initial issue, not the newest one?

Comment: I am fine with this issue. Thanks for asking .

Comment: In firebase auth, when using different providers with the same email address, the email address of the provider used later becomes hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

The simple Solution is to enable multiple account an email.
[image]

Or ----------------

You Link the account.

This is an example when there is a facebook account with a certain email
and you want to use that same email to sign in with Email and password or gmail, if those two emails are not linked different provider error will be thrown. check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) for more

```
 export function linkFaceBookAccount(authContext?: AuthContextType, notificationContext?: NotificationContextType, history?: History.History) {
const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider(); // create a provider

linkWithPopup(auth.currentUser as User, provider).then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    // const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    // const token = credential?.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    saveUserToLocalStorage(user);
    authContext?.loadUserToState(user);

    notificationContext?.addNotification({
        message: `This email's (${auth.currentUser?.email}) account has been successful linked with your facebook account`,
        title: "Link successful",
        notificationType: "SUCCESS",
        positiveActionText: "continue",
        positiveAction: () => {
            history?.push("/")
        }
    })
}).catch((error) => {

    const email = error.customData?.email;
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const duplicateAccount = errorCode === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential";
    notificationContext?.addNotification({
        message: errorFirebase(error, email),
        title: "Linking Error",
        notificationType: "WARNING",
        positiveActionText: duplicateAccount ? "Link" : "ok",
        negativeActionText: duplicateAccount ? "cancel" : undefined,
        code: errorCode,
        positiveAction: () => {
            if (duplicateAccount) {
                duplicateAccountLinking(email, "FACEBOOK", history);
            }
        }
    })
});}
```